# Good list of exercises in Hatcher’s book algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

I’m doing self study of Hatcher’s book on algebraic topology. There are too many exercises after each section and try to solve all the exercises needs a lot of work and definitely not an efficient and effective way of study. So is there a good list of the selected exercises?

Comment: Why are you reading the book in the first place, if doing the exercises is too much trouble?

Comment: I suggest an alternate strategy. Try to do only the exercises, ignoring the text entirely. Use the text solely as a means of getting a minimal understanding of the statement of the exercise and how to solve it. You'll learn soooo much more this way than the way you propose.

Comment: @LeeMosher Even with that method, doing each and every exercise in the book would still take longer than doing exercises curated by a lecturer. It may not be in the best interest of (nor even altogether more instructive for) the OP to take that kind of time to learn algebraic topology.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~ralph/math215a/) are [two](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~dmargalit7/classes/math6441Spring2019/) webpages for courses based off of Hatcher’s book that include problem selections.